# How do I purge all pages in cache of mediawiki?

Tags: php, api, caching, mediawiki

With the api, I can purge certain pages if I know the title:

```
http://mywiki.de/mediawiki/api.php?action=purge&titles=Page_With_Known_Title
```

But this will only purge cache of the page `Page_With_Known_Title`

I tried the `generator=allpages` option, but that didn't work either.

How do I purge all sites?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't explan how to use the api for all sites, but it clears the cache:

```
touch /etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php
```

because in the touch `LocalSettings.php` file there is this part:

```
# When you make changes to this configuration file, this will make
# sure that cached pages are cleared.
$wgCacheEpoch = max( $wgCacheEpoch, gmdate( 'YmdHis', @filemtime( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

`__FILE__` is the `LocalSettings.php` file itself, so if the filetime is now, all cache older than the file will be purged.